# Beat phenomenon when amplitudes of sine waves are different?

Tags: trigonometry

A radio receiver receives a signal of the form :
$A_{1}\sin\big(2\pi(f+\Delta f)t\big)+A_{0}\sin(2\pi f t)$.

I want to describe the beat phenomenon when $\Delta f\ll f$.
This is easy when $A_{0}=A_{1}$.

But when both amplitudes are different I want to prove the claim that the resultant amplitude never becomes 0.

The result can be considered as the sum of two beat terms :

Term 1 : $\displaystyle(A_{1}+A_{0})\cos\left(2\pi\frac{\Delta f}{2}t\right)\sin\left(2\pi\left[f+\frac{\Delta f}{2}\right]t\right)$.

Term 2 : $\displaystyle(A_{1}-A_{0})\cos\left(2\pi\left[f+\frac{\Delta f}{2}\right]t\right)\sin\left(2\pi\frac{\Delta f}{2}t\right)$.

But here I'm stuck.

Comment: The reverse triangle inequality,$$|a - b| \geq \bigl||a| - |b|\bigr|,\qquad\text{all real $a$, $b$,}$$seems likely to help. ;)